# Mongo match array of dates to the current date

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have a date array in my mongo collection. This is how my collection

```
[
   {
      "requestedDays":[
         {
            "full":[
               "ISODate(""2020-11-26T05:00:00.000+07:00"")",
               "ISODate(""2020-11-26T05:00:00.000+07:00"")"
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "requestedDays":[
         {
            "full":[
               "ISODate(""2020-11-24T05:00:00.000+07:00"")",
               "ISODate(""2020-11-26T05:00:00.000+05:00"")"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I need to match all the dates of array item **full** to current date. If all the items greater than current date it should return the object

Comment: Are they two different documents?

Comment: yes they both different @Gibbs